# Join two table have the same foreign key from Third table

Tags: sql

I have three table look like

1.Table Branch
**BranchID** = FK
**Name**
**Address**
**Contact**

2.Table Staff
**Staff_ID** = FK
**Name
Address
Gender
Contact**
**Supervisor_ID** = if does not have a supervisor then NULL
**BranchID**

3.Table Manager
**Staff_ID** = FK
**Name
Address
Gender
Contact
BranchID**

I would like to produce a listing showing the staff distribution at each branch. Include the branch number, manager name, total number of supervisors, and total number of male and female staff for each branch.

How do I retrieve a result set as above using an sql statement?

Below is my query

select Manager.Name,Branch.BranchNum,count(case when Supervisor_ID is null then 1 else null end) as NumberofSupervisor,count(case when Staff.gender='Male' and Supervisor_ID is not null then 1 else null end ) as Male, count(case when Staff.gender='Female' and Supervisor_ID is not null then 1 else null end)as female from Branch join Manager on Branch.BranchNum=Manager.BranchNum join Staff on Branch.BranchNum=Staff.BranchNum group by Branch.BranchNum

I get this error Column 'Manager.Name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Could you please guide me?

Thank you.

Comment: So what is preventing you? Can you share what you have tried and why it isn't working correctly?

Comment: I think you meant to say that the ID columns are Primary Keys for their respective tables ;)

Comment: Could you please share table structures of the tables that you want to join and exact result detail in your question?

Comment: i want to produce a listing showing the staff distribution at each branch. Include the branch number, manager name, total number of supervisors, and total number of male and female staff for each branch.

Comment: Alright i have figure out the way, Thx guys